# full pdist2 from Matlab to python

Tags: python, matlab

I'm trying to convert Matlab code to Python as project for an exam.
I cannot found any tips on how to convert this statement:

`[~, I] = pdist2(X,Y,'euclidean','Smallest',1)`

matlab doc: https://it.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html#mw_e8e43b52-bb7d-4183-9572-cc80c7ca5e84

I've checked some questions here but nothing seems to be equal to this case, because I need the "I" output parameter!

Also the already built in scipy.spatial.distance.pdist / cdist will not work correctly for me because they return only the "D" distance points that I really don't need it.

Do you know any tips / function to call to do this? Thank you!

Comment: For the future, try typing `edit pdist2` (or whatever other function) in Matlab, in most cases, you will see the Matlab function, which you can then convert to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.random.randn(25,2)
Y = np.random.randn(15,2)

D = np.zeros(len(X))
I = np.zeros(len(X))

for i,p in enumerate(Y):
    ed = np.sqrt(np.sum((p-X)**2,axis=1))
    D[i] = ed.min()
    I[i] = ed.argmin() + 1
```

Since indexing in Matlab is one-based and not zero-based like in Python, all the values of `I` must be increased by `1`. Once the computations have been performed, you will have the minimum distances in the `D` array and the indices to their corresponding `X` offset in the `I` array.

---

Given your sample data:

```
X = np.array([[0.8147,0.9134],[0.9058, 0.6324],[0.1270 ,0.0975]])
Y = np.array([[0.2785,0.9649],[0.5469, 0.1576],[0.9575 ,0.9706]])
```

the output is:

```
D => array([ 0.53866751,  0.42417923,  0.15383004])
I => array([ 1.,  3.,  1.])
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. doing a test with the same datas on ML and PY:

MATLAB:
X = 0.8147    0.9134
    0.9058    0.6324
    0.1270    0.0975
Y = 0.2785    0.9649
    0.5469    0.1576
    0.9575    0.9706
[D,I] = pdist2(X,Y,'euclidean','Smallest',1)
D =0.5387    0.4242    0.1538
I =1   3   1

python:
X = np.array([[0.8147,0.9134],[0.9058, 0.6324],[0.1270 ,0.0975]])
Y = np.array([[0.2785,0.9649],[0.5469, 0.1576],[0.9575 ,0.9706]])
D= [0.15383004 0.34212882 0.42417923]
I= [2. 2. 1.]

something is not working or i'm doing it wrong?

Comment: It's a formatting problem, X and Y they are both matrix given from rand(3,2)

Comment: OK I found the solution... the computation is not performed on an iteration of the points of `X` over all the points of `Y`... but on the opposite sense. I Edited my Python code to provide the right solution.

Comment: Ouch really nice to know that! Beautiful, thanks really a lot! I've marked your solution as best! I'll continue with the last part of the project! Again thanks really a lot!